# XML Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, xml

I want to read this XML but it only gives me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(responseString);

string valueX = doc.Root.Element("reponse").Element("point").Element("x").Value;
string valueY = doc.Root.Element("reponse").Element("point").Element("y").Value;

Console.WriteLine("TEST");
Console.WriteLine("Timb East" + valueX);
Console.WriteLine("Timb North" + valueY);
```

And here are my responseString XML example, I want to take value of X and Y.

```
<reponse><point><x>12557735.513928</x><y>5500887.2196169</y><projection>EPSG::29873</projection></point></reponse>
```

Can anybody give me a clue what is going wrong here? Thank you.

EDIT: fixed the response spelling to reponse.

Comment: Spelling:  XML contains `<reponse>` (misspelled) but your c# code uses `Element("response")` (spelled correctly).

Comment: @dbc Thanks for highlighting the spelling error! But after I fixed the spelling, still the same error output.

Comment: Oh right, you're doing `doc.Root.Element("response")` but `Root` is already the root element so you just need to do `doc.Element("response")` or `doc.Root.Element("point")`.

Answer (score 0):

Something is not as you might think.

Any call to `Element` may return `null`

[XContainer.Element(XName) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> A XElement that matches the specified XName, or null.

If you are unsure, use a [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

```
string valueX = doc.Root.Element("response")?.Element("point")?.Element("x")?.Value;
```

However, more than likely it's not parsing as you would expect, or the data is not what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

What if you change your code like below to use `GetElementsByTagName()` method present in `XmlDocument` type

```
        string msg = "<response><point><x>12557735.513928</x><y>5500887.2196169</y><projection>EPSG::29873</projection></point></response>";             
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(msg);
        var valueX = doc.GetElementsByTagName("x")[0].InnerText;
        string valueY = doc.GetElementsByTagName("y")[0].InnerText;

        Console.WriteLine("TEST");
        Console.WriteLine("Timb East" + valueX);
        Console.WriteLine("Timb North" + valueY);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I would recommend that OP revert back to the older `XmlDocument` API.  Also, in [the documentation for `GetElementsByTagName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementsbytagname?view=netframework-4.7.2) Microsoft writes, *It is recommended that you use the XmlNode.SelectNodes or XmlNode.SelectSingleNode method instead of the GetElementsByTagName method.*

Answer (score 0):

Two problems, both regarding how you access the root element:

1. There is mismatch (spelling inconsistency) between the root element name in the XML and the root element name expected by your code.

   The XML contains the root element `<reponse>` (misspelled) but your c# code uses `"response"` (spelled correctly).

   You need to fix the code and XML root element names to be consistent.
2. When you do

   ```
   doc.Root.Element("response")...
   ```

   You are trying to access a *child element named `<response>`* of the root element of the XML document.  But `<response>` (or `<reponse>`) *is already* the root element, and has no such child.  Thus you need to do:

   ```
   var valueX = doc.Root.Element("point").Element("x").Value;
   ```

   Or

   ```
   var valueX = doc.Element("reponse").Element("point").Element("x").Value;
   ```

   (I.e. `doc.Root` and `doc.Element("reponse")` are doing the same thing, namely return the root element, so there is no need to do both.)

Sample fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CrsDRN).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the xml contains only one `<x>` and `<y>` node, you can try below code

```
 System.Xml.Linq.XElement xml = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse("<response><point><x>12557735.513928</x><y>5500887.2196169</y><projection>EPSG::29873</projection></point></response>");

            var valueX = xml.Descendants().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "x")?.Value;
            var valueY = xml.Descendants().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "y")?.Value;
            Console.WriteLine("TEST");
            Console.WriteLine("Timb East" + valueX);
            Console.WriteLine("Timb North" + valueY);
```